# Stop a loop in WSO2 ESB

Tags: loops, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I was wondering if I could stop an Iterator mediator or a foreach mediator in WSO2 ESB in-between i.e. Is there a `break;`(statement in Java) equivalent in WSO2 ESB.

Can I use `<drop/>` mediator to achieve the same ?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this is not supported. It is already [reported as an improvement](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4517) and will be fixed in a future release of ESB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !!

Answer (score 0):

With version 7.2.0, you can use the `<respond/>` to break the *`foreach mediator`*